# Search in enum for status code using error code

Tags: java

I have this enum structure which is used to store error responses:

```
public enum ErrorDetail implements CjmErrorInfo {

    JOURNEY_NOT_FOUND("1000", "not found", "not found", "not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND),

    private String errorCode;
    private String message;
    private String detail;
    private String title;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;

    public String getErrorCode()
    {
        return this.errorCode;
    }

    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus(){
        return this.httpStatus;
    }
}
```

But I want to get the http status (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) based on the error code. How this can be implemented?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a static method to your `enum` like the following:

```
  public static ErrorDetail getByErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    return Arrays.stream(Test.values()).filter(errorDetail -> errorDetail.getErrorCode().equals(errorCode))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
  }
```

By the way, your `enum` is missing a constructor! It is needed to define all those fields on the enum constants, otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
public String getHttpStatusBasedOnErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    for(ErrorDetail e : ErrorDetail.values()) {
        if(errorCode.equals(e.getErrorCode())) {
            return e.getHttpStatus().toString();
        }
    }
    return "error code not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hold static map that uses errorCode or message (or other field) as a key and the enum element as a value. In this case you can easily implement method like `getErrorDetailByMessage()` that just brings the value from that map.

However you can avoid writing this code yourself. Occasionally I have implemented library named "enums" that does this and a lot of other things. Take a look on https://github.com/alexradzin/enumus in github.

You can also read my article ["customized valueOf"](https://dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-customized-valueof).